# ParallelQuery core balancing

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, plinq

I have 200,000 tasks that will run in parallel for speed gains. I'm using `ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, 200000).Sum( a => /*do_something*/ )`.

as the task counter goes from 0 to 200,000 the required number of iterations decreases. The task with `a=0` requires most number of iterations, while tasks with `a>100,000` finish with one or no iteration.

due to this, my quad-core machine isn't reaching max cpu utilization peak as the tasks progress. It seems like the workload is distributed to all 4 cores at start, and some cores go idle earlier as their portion was mainly tasks with high `a`s. cpu utilization starts with 100%, but drops gradually to 75~50~25%. How can I achieve full cpu utilization from start to end?

Comment: Have you tried logging the order of execution to see what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple self-answer : replacing `ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, 200000)` with `Enumerable.Range(...).AsParallel()` was enough to solve this problem. The it seems that the workload is distributed dynamically in `Enumerable.Range(...).AsParallel()`.

Comment: That's not much of an answer: it doesn't explain *why* it works faster. Using something without knowing why can be quite dangerous.